# Disable Puma on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby with Puma platform

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, puma

Is it possible to stop or disable the Puma server on AWS Elastic Beanstalk Ruby + Puma? I'm using the Thin server instead and I would like to save on resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the following to my 01_nginx.config file in .ebextensions to disable Puma:

```
files:
  "/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/conf/pumaconf.rb":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      directory '/var/app/current'
      threads 0
      workers 0
      bind 'unix:///var/run/puma/my_app.sock'
      pidfile '/var/run/puma/puma.pid'
      stdout_redirect '/var/log/puma/puma.log', '/var/log/puma/puma.log', true
      daemonize false
```